# How to get my delete method to accept null values?

Tags: c#, if-statement, controller, null

Right now this method will delete a job post that has all the fields filled in. I need it to delete the job even if all the fields are not filled in (accept null values). Here is the controller method:

```
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)  // triggered when Delete "Job Title" is pressed
        {
            Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id);  // finds Job to delete in Jobs table
            ShiftTime shift = db.ShiftTime.Find(id);  //  finds shifttimes attached to Job being deleted in ShiftTimes table
            JobOther other = db.JobOthers.Find(id); //  finds JobsOthers attached to Job being deleted in JobOthers table
            var schedules = db.Schedules.Where(x => x.Job.JobIb == id);    // finds list of schedules attached to Job being deleted in Schedules table
            foreach (Schedule schedule in schedules)  //  iterates through list of schedules attached to Job being deleted....
            {
                db.Schedules.Remove(schedule);  // ...and removes schedules
            }
            db.ShiftTime.Remove(shift);  // removes ShiftTimes
            db.JobOthers.Remove(other); // removes JobOthers
            db.Jobs.Remove(job);  // removes actual Job
            db.SaveChanges();   // finally saves changes to each table
            return RedirectToAction("Index"); // returns to "Index" list of Jobs 

        }
```

I'm thinking that I'll have to include some if/else statements but I have tried so many different variations to no avail.

Comment: Your problem is not well detailed. However, If this properties are navigation properties, you can enable cascade delete on each relationship to delete it automatically when the parent object (job) is deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that for a given `id` there is always a `job` but there may not be the other objects `shift, other, schedules`. To get `job` to delete with others being null, do a null check before the delete methods:

```
if (schedules != null) 
{ 
    // the foreach 
}
...
if (shift != null) db.ShiftTime.Remove(shift);
...
if (other != null) db.JobOthers.Remove(other);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! So far, that part works. Now I am getting another error on db.SaveChanges(); --System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException HResult=0x80131501

Comment: No problem! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the new error you're getting. A brief search tells me it may be a problem with your models/database. Are Keys being set correctly? Are the relationships correct? I suspect the to-be-deleted job's id exists in another table.

Comment: I was going to say in my original answer to your first problem, it might be worth investigating why you "need it to delete the job even if all the fields are not filled in (accept null values)". Maybe the question should have been: why are they null?

This might lead you to review your models and make changes or decide to do this delete method differently. Entity Framework makes it easy to delete related objects by default so I'm not sure why this is happening to you at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

instead of

```
db.Jobs.Remove(job);
```